# How call an event only one time for multiple buttons on jquery?

Tags: jquery, events, button

I display multiple buttons dynamically, and I want to do an event only 1 time when I click on one button, so when the event is done if I click on any button I want to do nothing.

Here is my code. When I try it it works for each button, so if I have 3 buttons I can do 3 events and I want only 1 :

```
$('.btnSupp').one("click",  function(){
    if ($('.btnSupp').is("btn-danger")) {
    } else {
        var r = $('<a href="#">Enregistrer</a>');
        $("body").append(r);
    }
});
```

Comment: SO you are saying you have 3 btn-supp and only once should it be clicked no matter which button right?

Comment: If you don't need to use any of these buttons afterward, why not change their class. For example before using they have the class "readyToUse", and once you click one button, you all switch them to the class "notReadyToUse"?

Comment: why is this tagged as php?

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner i think it's within the php project but yep you're right that's strange

Comment: @LilianBarraud there's no code to support the tag, which makes it unclear and misleading to those who follow that tag; such as myself. ;-)

Comment: yes because its a php project ^^'

Comment: @LoïcRivera yeah, and? where's the code and relevance for it?

Comment: vorting as unclear.

Comment: @RAHULSR I have 3 button and 1 event for them. when i click in any button 1 time the event run but i want when i click on another button or same button, dont run the event

Comment: @mplungjan what do you mean?

Comment: @mplungjan not with that php tag. It's misleading to those who follow that tag such as I.

Comment: @mplungjan thanks ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [off](http://api.jquery.com/off/)

I also fixed a class selector and removed the unnecessary if and made it point at the clicked button

If delegated:

```
$(document).on("click", '.btnSupp', function(){
  if (!$(this).is(".btn-danger")) {
    var r = $('<a href="#">Enregistrer</a>');
    $("body").append(r);
  }
  $(document).off("click", '.btnSupp')
});
```

If not

```
$('.btnSupp').on("click", function(){
  if (!$(this).is(".btn-danger")) {
    var r = $('<a href="#">Enregistrer</a>');
    $("body").append(r);
  }
  $('.btnSupp').off("click")
});
```

If you want to be VERY specific, use a named function as suggested by Kaddath and also shown in the link to the documentation:

```
function enri(){
  if (!$(this).is(".btn-danger")) {
    var r = $('<a href="#">Enregistrer</a>');
    $("body").append(r);
  }
  $(document).off("click", '.btnSupp', enri);
}

$(document).on("click", '.btnSupp', enri);
```

Comment: he is displaying buttons dynamically dont he needs to bind it with dom?

Comment: you should add a precision that this will remove all click events bound to the buttons, if there are other actions to be performed, they will be removed too. The OP can still use a named function to specifically remove this one instead of all.

Comment: The off is specifically removing the click in this case

Comment: this is just in case more than one function were bound to these buttons (which is not the most common case, i admit)

Comment: I have added the last example

Answer (score 0):

You can use `off` to disassociate the click event. The `.off()` method removes event handlers that were attached with `.on()`.

**Change your code from**

```
$('.btnSupp').on("click",  function(){
    if ($('.btnSupp').is("btn-danger")) {
    } else {
        var r = $('<a href="#">Enregistrer</a>');
        $("body").append(r);
    }
});
```

**to**

```
$('.btnSupp').on("click", function1);

   function1(){
      if ($('.btnSupp').is("btn-danger")) {

  } else {
      var r = $('<a href="#">Enregistrer</a>');
      $("body").append(r);
  }
  //stop listening to function1 but will listen for other function 
  $('.btnSupp').off("click", function1);
}
```

Comment: Thats works but i have an another event for all the button when i click de color change so when i do the "off" the another event doesnt work

Comment: No. You are using `one` and I am using `on` because `off` works on `on`